# Is there an AIR based software to learn Flex

Tags: apache-flex, air

There is a AIR based software where in you can see as demos as well as code.. I forgot its name.. can anyone please let me know.. the software is from Adobe.

Answer (score 4):

Tour de Flex is perhaps most notorious.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html

AIR Installer: http://download.macromedia.com/pub/developer/air/TourDeFlex.air
Web Version: http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/tourdeflex/web/

Although not kept as current, the following links prove useful at times.

Flex Component Explorer:

http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/componentexplorer/explorer.html

Flex Style Explorer:

http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html#app=a712&19f4-selectedIndex=23&1b1e-selectedIndex=0&b108-selectedIndex=0

Comment: +1 for Component Explorer, didn't know about that. I often use another one tool - RegExp Explorer http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/